# Bad timing Apollo Subscription

Tags: apollo

I have some troubles with the subscriptions, the logic is implemented and works , i just want to get the token as soon as i get logged ( i can get it when i do a refresh and that’s not the way i want it )

I’m using apollo client with subscriptions-transport-ws and I initialise the client like that

```
const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient(SUB_ENDPOINT, {
reconnect: true,
timeout: 30000,
connectionParams: {
token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(‘token’))
}
})
```

If anyone have a clue where this can come from it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen two ways of tackling this. I haven’t tried either, yet.

You can close the connection on authentication wsClient.close(false, false), or create a split link with authenticated and unauthenticated routes.

```
function isAuthenticated() { ... <true || false> }

const unauthenticatedLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:5000/`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
})

const authenticatedLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: `ws://localhost:5000/`,
    options: {
      reconnect: true,
      connectionParams: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }
  })

const link = split(
  () => isAuthenticated(),
  authenticatedLink,
  unauthenticatedLink
)
```

I’ll try them soon and report back.